# Avoiding multiple elif statements in Python parser for ArcGIS label expressions?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, labeling, python-parser, expression

My code for labels look like this:

```
 def FindLabel ( [NAME_GEO] ): 
  if [NAME_GEO]=="Tbilisi" :
     return "<BOL><FNT size ='14'>" + [NAME_GEO] + "</FNT></BOL>"
  elif [NAME_GEO]=="soxumi" :
     return "<BOL><FNT size ='12'>" + [NAME_GEO] + "</FNT></BOL>"
  elif [NAME_GEO]=="baTumi" :
     return "<BOL><FNT size ='12'>" + [NAME_GEO] + "</FNT></BOL>"
  else:
     return [NAME_GEO]
```

It works but as you can see there are two 'elif' statements for cities, which are pretty much the same. If I wish to have more city names with same label properties as it is for "soxumi" and "baTumi", I would need to add more 'elif' statements.
I wanted to change code, so there would be only one 'elif' statement for "soxumi", "baTumi" and any other cities, however I failed... could anyone suggest how to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
def FindLabel ( [NAME_GEO] ): 
  if [NAME_GEO]=="Tbilisi" :
     return "<BOL><FNT size ='14'>" + [NAME_GEO] + "</FNT></BOL>"
  elif [NAME_GEO] in ("soxumi", "baTumi") :
     return "<BOL><FNT size ='12'>" + [NAME_GEO] + "</FNT></BOL>"
  else:
     return [NAME_GEO]
```

Comment: @IrakliSkhirtladze - If this has worked please mark it as the answer.  See [What should I do when someone answers my question?](http://gis.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)